# How to show the given sequence is Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\left\{ X_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty }$ be a real sequence that satisfies $\left| X_{n}-X_{n+1}\right| \leq \dfrac {\left| X_{n-1}-X_{n}\right| } {2}$ for every $n>1$. How can I show $\left\{ X_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty }$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: The Nitpicking Department reports that in your first line, $X_{n-1}$ was not defined for $n=1$ . My edit was to change "for every $n$" to "for every $n>1$"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show that the given sequence is Cauchy, then let $\epsilon>0$ and let $N$ be so large that $2^{-N} < \epsilon$. Then if $n>m> N$ you have (let $n = m+l$):
\begin{align*}
|X_n - X_m| &= |X_{m+l}-X_m| \\
&\le |X_{m+l}-X_{m+l-1}|+\dotsb+|X_{m+1}-X_m| \\
&\le 2^{-(l-1)}|X_{m+1}-X_m|+\dotsb+|X_{m+1}-X_m| \\
&= |X_{m+1}-X_m|\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}2^{-k} \\
&\le 2^{-(m-1)}|X_2-X_1|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k} \\
&=2^{-(m-2)}|X_2-X_1|\\
&<C\epsilon|X_2-X_1|,
\end{align*}
where $C>0$ is a constant on the order of $\sim 2$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, $\{X_n\}$ is Cauchy. You may have to fiddle with the exponents to get the indexing right, but this is the main idea.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n < m$,
$$\begin{align}|X_m - X_n|
&\le |X_m - X_{m-1}| + \cdots + |X_{n+1} - X_n| & \text{triangle ineq.}\\
&\le |X_{n+1} - X_n| \left(2^{-(m-n-1)} + 2^{-(m-n-2)} + \cdots + 1\right) &\text{apply the condition to each term}\\
&\le 2|X_{n+1} - X_n| & \text{geom. series}
\\
&\le 2^{-(n-2)} |X_2 - X_1|. & \text{apply condition again}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

By induction on $n\geq 1$ we have $|X_{n+1}-X_n|\leq 2^{1-n}|X_2-X_1|$ for all $n\in \mathbb N.$

Given $\epsilon >0$, take $n$ large enough that $2^{1-n}|X_2-X_1|<\epsilon /2.$ Then for $n\leq m<m'$ we have $$\left|X_m-X_{m'}\right|\;=\;\left|\sum_{j=0}^{m'-m-1}(X_{m+j}-X_{m+j+1})\right|\;\leq\; \sum_{j=0}^{m'-m-1}|X_{m+j}-X_{m+j+1}|\;\leq$$    $$\leq \;\sum_{j=0}^{m'-m-1}2^{(1-m-j)}\cdot|X_2-X_1|\;=\;2^{1-m}\cdot|X_2-X_1|\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{m'-m-1}2^{-j}\;=$$ $$=\;2^{1-m}\cdot|X_2-X_1|\cdot(2-2^{-(m'-m-1)})\;\leq$$ $$\leq\; 2^{1-m}\cdot|X_2-X_1|\cdot 2\;\leq\; 2^{1-n}\cdot |X_2-X_1|\cdot 2\;<\;(\epsilon /2)\cdot 2\;=\;\epsilon.$$